# Unattend installation not working - "We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one"

Tags: windows, diskmanagement, automated-install, unattended

I can't seem to get an unattended installation to work it fails with:

"We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the Setup log files."

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently windows cannot install when there are 2 or more EFI partitions. Deleting the "Drive 1 partition 1" will probably allow for the installation to continue.